# Change packages from country local to global

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I want to reinstall all packages in Ubuntu 13.10 that were downloaded from my country local repository to change them to global repository versions. I can work on system that is completely English, so it is not a problem.

How can I exchange these packages (nearly all or find the country local)?
I would like not to loose configurations. If there is possibility that I would loose configurations - what folders should I backup to restore them later?

Comment: Please DO NOT change the sense of the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any such thing as country local and global versions of Ubuntu packages!

If you are just referring to what repository mirror you downloaded the packages from, that shouldn't make a difference, and there is nothing to "replace". Packages in the Ubuntu repository are cryptographically signed and ultimately verified against a release signing key so if a country-local repository mirror site wanted to make country-specific changes to packages then they wouldn't be able to get away with it anyway.

If you are referring to language packages like [firefox-locale-en](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/firefox-locale-en) and [firefox-locale-fr](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/firefox-locale-fr) then the different languages packages are actual different packages, and you install more languages by installing more packages, not by replacing anything.